# c# aforge simulate webcam ISP RGB Gain register change

Tags: c#, rgb, aforge

I'm developing a program which can simulate a webcam's ISP RGB gain register value. The simulated value will be sent to the vender to be hard coded to the device AP.

I noticed there are many filters inside Aforge, and even without it, I can use the newFrame() method to apply other filters to be displayed.

But, what filter( or algorithm ) should I use to simulate this ISP RGB gain register value? As far as I know there was no property simular to it inside

```
                videoDevice.DisplayPropertyPage(IntPtr.Zero);
```

.

Comment: The vender says that the RGB gain register value has a range of 0~4095.

Answer (score 0):

There are indeed a handful of filters, and I find the best one for your intended use to be the `GammaCorrection` filter:

```
GammaCorrection _filtroGamma = new GammaCorrection();
double _gamma = 1;  // should be between 0.1 and 5.0, 1.0 is the neutral value (does nothing)

void NewFrameHandler(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    var bitmap = eventArgs.Frame;
    _filtroGamma.Gamma = _gamma;
    _filtroGamma.ApplyInPlace(bitmap);
    DoSomething(bitmap);
}
```